# Fakeiteasy issue mocking soapclient

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, fakeiteasy

I'm trying to cover my business logic with unit tests using `NUnit` and `fakeiteasy`. But I suddenly stuck with faking calls to Soap client using fakeiteasy. I trying to do next thing

```
var myFakedSoapClient = A.Fake<SomeSoapClient>();
var myCustomServiceWhichUsesThatSoapClient = new MyService(myFakedSoapClient);
myCustomServiceWhichUsesThatSoapClient.CallDoSomething();   
myFakedSoapClient.CallsTo(e=>e.DoSomething(A<string>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
```

But in the first row in which I'm trying to fake SoapClient it just get stuck and start to eat more and more memory. It doesn't show any exception, it just run that line until timeout.

What I miss?

Thx for any advance.

Comment: What is `SomeSoapClient`? I'm not familiar with the class.

Comment: It is some soapclient which was auto generated by wsdl.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help.
FakeItEasy can fake many classes (although I'd recommend faking interfaces whenever possible—there are fewer surprises), so without knowing more about the class that's being faked, there's no way to reproduce the problem, and reasoning about it becomes quite difficult.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that `SoapClient` has anything to do with your business logic. I would ensure that you are isolating your business logic components from your integration components. Something that is calling a SOAP webservice is an integration component and you can apply an appropriate testing strategy to it. Indeed, if you isolate the SOAP client usage as far as possible to thinnest possible wrapper, there is little value in unit testing this, so the need to fake SoapClient will fall away.

Answer (score 1):

Include the fake call

```
myFakedSoapClient.CallsTo(e=>e.DoSomething(A<string>.Ignored)).WithAnyArgumemen().Returns(expectedfakeobject);
```

before the actual function call

```
var myCustomServiceWhichUsesThatSoapClient = new MyService(myFakedSoapClient);
```

Something like this

```
var myFakedSoapClient = A.Fake<SomeSoapClient>();
var myCustomServiceWhichUsesThatSoapClient = new MyService(myFakedSoapClient);
myFakedSoapClient.CallsTo(e=>e.DoSomething(A<string>.Ignored)).WithAnyArgumemen().Returns(expectedfakeobject);
myCustomServiceWhichUsesThatSoapClient.CallDoSomething();   
myFakedSoapClient.CallsTo(e=>e.DoSomething(A<string>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
```